# How do you create edgeless graphql element in Gatsby?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

The title may be miss leading but I'm not really sure how do I ask this question correctly. Here is the problem: I'd like to query my own API(not created yet so I made placeholder data) for global settings which might change in the future and I will only need to rebuild the website instead of editing it manually, I want to create source node called CmsSettings and pass it to GraphQL (structure similar to site.siteMetadata) but I don't know how can I achieve that. What I achieved so far is to create a source node called allCmsSettings which has my data as an object in nodes array.

```
exports.sourceNodes = ({ actions, createNodeId, createContentDigest }) => {
  const { createNode } = actions;
  const myData = {
    key: 123,
    app_title: `The foo field of my node`,
    ...
  }

  const nodeContent = JSON.stringify(myData);

  const nodeMeta = {
    id: createNodeId(`my-data${ myData.key }`),
    parent: null,
    children: [],
    internal: {
      type: `CmsSettings`,
      mediaType: `text/html`,
      content: nodeContent,
      contentDigest: createContentDigest(myData)
    }
  }

  const node = Object.assign({}, myData, nodeMeta);
  createNode(node);
}
```

Here is the query used to get the data of the source node

```
allCmsSettings {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        app_title
        ...
      }
    }
  }
```

Creating a query results in an array of results(which I know is the result of creating source nodes) but I'd like to create that source so that I could query it like this and:

```
CmsSettings {
  app_title
  app_keywords
  app_descriptions
  app_logo_path
  brand_name
  ...
}
```

You get the point. I was browsing the gatsby node API but I can't find how to achieve this.
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, the answer is pretty simple, if you are new to gatsby just like me the sourceNodes export creates 2 graphql fields for you with all prefix and camel case source node. The thing that I wanted to make is already there and is queryable with

```
cmsSettings {
  app_title
  app_keywords
  app_descriptions
  app_logo_path
  brand_name
  ...
}
```

Notice the lowercase letter even though it was declared as CmsSettings. It seems that gatsby really does some magic under the hood.